# Location of Django Admin media files on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-admin

I am running GoogleAppEngine (GAE) 1.6.3 with Python 2.7 and Django 1.3 by having:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
```

in my `app.yaml`. The following should serve the admin media files at url `/static/admin`:

```
- url: /static/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'
```

But I get 404s for such admin media (css, etc). Am I using the correct location for the Django admin's media file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to copy or symlink the `media` directory into your app directory in your local files, so it is uploaded with your app's files.  Then your `app.yaml` can refer to the relative path in the app directory.

There is a `$PYTHON_LIB` variable substitution you can use in `app.yaml` paths, but it looks like Django is not under `$PYTHON_LIB` in the live version of the Python 2.7 runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have your book too, very good book though a bit outdated today. So there is no way to set a  GAE static file handler to point to the Django admin media on Live? I've sorted it out the usual way locally, Live is the problem. So I have to upload all Django Admin media files, correct? I thought I could avoid this.

Comment: Had to copy all the files and place them with rest of the files for upload. Admin static files alone are 640Kb. That's more than half of my whole application! Any plan to "fix" this? Thanks!

Comment: The static file servers are entirely separate from the app servers, and so don't have their own copy of Django. If you want the static file servers to serve these, they have to be uploaded as part of your app. Another option would be to write a little handler that serves them from the app servers, which could find the Django directory using `inspect.getfile(django)` or something like that. (And thanks for the compliment on the book; I'm actively working on a 2nd edition. :) )

Comment: Fair enough. Accepted this as solution.

Answer (score 1):

When adding this to `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /static/admin
  static_dir: static/admin
  expiration: '0'
```

I was able to serve the CSS files by:

Adding this to `settings.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + os.sep
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + 'static'
```

And then running

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

The admin media files appear correctly locally as well as on appspot.com.
The last command copies the media files into the the `static/` directory. So in fact does what Dan Sanderson suggested but in a more automated way.

Comment: Will not unmark the other answer as correct, as I can't verify your soultion is correct as I'm currently not using GAE. Still sounds "neater", i.e. +1ed

Comment: This works for me! BTW I use "/static" and "static/" instead of "/static/admin" and "static/admin" in the handlers section of app.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Philipp Keller's `collectstatic`, but I don't have that command available.

So, add this handler to `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /static/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/static/admin
  expiration: '0'
```

then, in `settings.py`, delete `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` (removed in django 1.4) and add:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and you have working css.

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore. Still +1ed since this is a more recent answer.

Answer (score 0):

is possible static file referenced by variable $PYTHON_LIB on deploy ??

file app.yaml

```
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"

handlers:
- url: /admin/media
  static_dir: $PYTHON_LIB/lib/django_1_3/django/contrib/admin/media

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
```

**log local:**

INFO     2012-04-03 02:06:19,200 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /admin/media/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

INFO     2012-04-03 02:06:19,207 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /admin/media/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

INFO     2012-04-03 02:06:19,242 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /admin/media/img/admin/default-bg.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -

**log error deploy app:**

2012-04-02 19:17:32.775 /admin/media/css/dashboard.css 404 6ms 0kb

- - [02/Apr/2012:19:17:32 -0700] "GET /admin/media/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404

Static file referenced by handler not found:$PYTHON_LIB/lib/django_1_3/django/contrib/admin/media/css/dashboard.css

Comment: Follow the comments in Dan Sanderson's answer above.

Comment: OK Thanks. The static file servers are entirely separate from the app servers.    I do not like the solution to copy the static files to my application

Comment: Yep it slows it a bit down too. Take a look at this related discussion on [performance howtos on GAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941691/django-on-googleappengine-performance-howto).

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to work fine for me.

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: staticfiles
```

**settings**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Run `python manage.py collectstatic`. Now under your staticfiles admin folder should be created.